# Loading DDS textures?

Tags: opengl, textures, dds-format

I'm reading about loading DDS textures. I read [this](http://www.oldunreal.com/editing/s3tc/ARB_texture_compression.pdf) article and saw [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/637377-loading-dds-textures-in-opengl-black-texture-showing/) posting. (I also read the [wiki about S3TC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression))

I understood most of the code, but there's two lines I didn't quite get.

```
blockSize = (format == GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT) ? 8 : 16;
```

and:

```
size = ((width + 3) / 4) * ((height + 3) / 4) * blockSize;
```

and:

```
bufsize = mipMapCount > 1 ? linearSize * 2 : linearSize;
```

1. What is `blockSize`? and why are we using `8` for `DXT1` and `16` for the rest?
2. What is happening exactly when we're calculating `size`? More
   specifically why are we adding `3`, dividing by `4` then multiplying
   by `blockSize`?
3. Why are we multiplying by `2` if `mipMapCount > 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DXT1-5 formats are also called BCn formats (it ends with numbers but not exactly the same ones) and BC stands for block compression. Pixels are not stored separately, it only stores a block of data for the equivalent of 4x4 pixels.

The **1st** line checks if it's DXT1, because it has a size of 8 byte per block. DXT3 and DXT5 have use 16 bytes per block. (Note that newer formats exist and at least one of them is 8 bytes/block: BC4).

The **2nd** rounds up the dimensions of the texture to a multiple of the dimensions of a block. This is required since these formats can only store blocks, not pixels. For example, if you have a texture of 15x6 pixels, and since BCn blocks are 4x4 pixels, you will need to store 4 blocks per column, and 2 blocks per row, even if the last column/row of blocks will only be partially filled.

One way of rounding up a positive integer (let's call it `i`) to a multiple of another positive integer (let's call it `m`), is:

```
(i + m - 1) / m * m
```

Here, we need get the number of blocks on each dimension and then multiply by the size of a block to get the total size of the texture. To do that we round up `width` and `height` to the next multiple of 4, divide by 4 to get the number of block and finally and multiply it by the size of the block:

```
size = (((width + 3) / 4 * 4) * ((height + 3) / 4 * 4)) / 4 * blockSize;
//                         ^                        ^     ^
```

If you look closely, there's a *4 followed by a /4 that can be simplified. If you do that, you'll get exactly the same code you had. The conclusion to all this could be comment any code that's not perfectly obvious :P

The **3rd** line *may be* an approximation to calculate a buffer size big enough to store the whole mipmap chain easily. But I'm not sure what this `linearSize` is; it correspond to `dwPitchOrLinearSize` in the [DDS header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In any case, you don't really need this value since you can calculate the size of each level easily with the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate more on the second line? Not sure what you mean by `N-1`? it seems that this 'size' is the size of a mipmap? I say that because then he's reading from the buffer by 'size' amount. Why can't we just do `width * height * blockSize`? The 'size' calculation has to be correct and accurate because we're incrementing our `offset` by it which we then add to our `buffer` to read the next mipmap. Wouldn't rounding yield inaccurate results in this case? (cause it's not the actual size of the mipmap)

Comment: I edited my post to add more explanations for the 2nd line (and a little bit for the others too). Tell me if something's left unclear.

Comment: Not sure about the simplification part.  Let `w` denote `width+3` and `h` denote `height+3` we get `(w / 4 * 4) * (h /  4 * 4) / 4 * blockSize` = `w * h / 4 * blockSize`? even if you meant `(w / (4 * 4))` ... it still won't equal the initial code cause there's only one 4 to simplify. am I missing something?

Comment: I added parenthesis and `^` below the fours that can be simplified. Note that `w / 4 * 4` in your comment cannot be simplified to `w` because it's an integer division (eg. 3 / 4 = 0 so 3 / 4 * 4 is still 0, not 3). Simplifying `w * 4 / 4`, however, is safe.